# SAP DCOM Connector on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, ado, sap, dcom

Does anybody know, if it is possible to use the "old" SAP DCOM Connector on a Windows Server 2008 ?

I want to migrate a old ASP Web Solution with DCOM Connection to SAP from Windows 2000 Server to Windows 2008 Server.

When I try to install the DCOM Connector I get the Error Message:

"Setup could not find ActivX(R) Data Objects verion 2.5 or higher on your computer...."

That is strange, because ado is there under C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\ado !

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to make it work even on windows 2003 server. I don't remember how hard I tried. But its certainly not supported event for windows 2003. And actually this component is out of support since 2005 or something like this.